# List all my beans loaded by SpringApplication.run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to enlist all the beans written by me when I boot up the SpringApplication.

Getting *all* the beans listed is done. This code does it.

```
String[] beanNames = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();

Arrays.sort(beanNames);
for (String beanName : beanNames) {
        System.out.println(beanName);
}
```

I tried using a basic filter to look for *my stuff*.

```
String[] beanNames = appContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();

Arrays.sort(beanNames);
for (String beanName : beanNames) {
    if (beanName.matches("(.*)Controller"))
        System.out.println(beanName);
}
```

But that does not work because when the classes are loaded it is really the bean name that is loaded and not the exact name of the classes. So if I wrote a *my.personal.package.structure.MyController* it would most probably show up as *myController*. The package structure information is lost rendering this technique, not quite effective.

Has anyone tried some other way that worked. I expect this to be very handy for a developer for debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `ConfigurableApplicationContext` you can get all bean types. For example:

```
@Autowired
ConfigurableApplicationContext context;
.....
ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beansFactory = context.getBeanFactory();
String[] beansNames =  beansFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();
Set<String> beansType = new HashSet<>();

for(String beanName : beansNames){
    if (beanName.matches("(.*)Controller")){
       beansType.add(beansFactory.getType(beanName).toString());
    }
}
```

Other easier option to show all the beans is
In the case you are using spring-web You could use `Spring boot actuator`. Add the next [dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator) in your `pom.xml` and go to the `/bean` endpoint to show all beans, and it will put the name of the bean and the class.

Comment: I added **spring-boot-starter-actuator** and hit **localhost:8080/beans**. I got a long list of all the beans that were loaded up, I guess. But I was looking for a way of listing down only the beans that I added. So, no, this is not what I was looking for.

Comment: Have you seen my second option? You just have to add your matches condition to it....

Comment: I am trying the second option. But till now, no luck.

Comment: You need to inject ConfigurableApplicationContext